# SharePoint 2013 Custom FBA user access issues

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have implemented a custom FBA solution in SharePoint 2013 
using this link http://sivarajan.me/post/sharepoint-2013-custom-claims-fba-based-mixed-mode-authentication-part-1

1)FBA users got "sorry this site has not been shared with you"

I followed the below steps and now all fba users can view the site

- On Central Administration, navigate to Application Management -> Under Web Applications: Manage web applications
- Select your My Site -web application by clicking it, and open Permission Policy
- Click Add Permission Policy Level
- Enter at least the Name for your Permission Policy
- Select following Permissions:

  **Create Subsites**  -  Create subsites such as team sites, Meeting Workspace sites, and Document Workspace sites.

  **View Pages**  -  View pages in a Web site.

  **Browse User Information**  -  View information about users of the Web site.

  **Open**  -  Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in order to access items inside that container.
- Leave other parts unmarked and click Save
- Make sure your My Site -web application is selected and open User Policy
- Click Add Users, and on first view leave Zones: (All zones) selected, then click Next >
- On Choose Users -part click Browse (the catalogue type of icon). Click All Users and select Everyone activated. Press Add -> and OK
- On Choose Permissions, select the Permission Policy you recently created
- Click Finish

I have 3 documents libraries directory under the root

partners.contoso.com/documents1
partners.contoso.com/documents2
partners.contoso.com/documents3

I have following FBA users test1, test2,test3

When test1 logs in it should only be able to see documents1 
test2 --> documents2
test3 --> documents3

I have not implemented the asp.net role manager as I am controlling that in SharePoint user group

When test1 logs in it is able to view all the document libraries (documents1,documents2,documents3)

Is it because asp.net role  is not implemented ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your users will see all document libraries and lists as you granted them permissions to do that by your permission policy (Open permission particularly). That permission policy has web application scope so will allow all users (as you selected Everyone) to see all webs sites, document libraries and lists in all sites and site collection within defined web application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure a few things have been set.

Make sure that you have edited the web.config files for the STS web service, central admin and the web application.

Check your event logs as this will help find any issues.

You may also run into permission issues with the database.  Can you make sure the application pool accounts for all three have read access to the database.

Chances are your central admin is configured but either the STS and\or the web application is not.